How to make both div 100% fill inside another div and overlap together?
Not by using position: absolute; because they are needed to be inside that parent div. But how to make them overlap? iframe is not a choice as well.


<div id='parent' style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellowgreen;">
  <div id='child-1' style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: orange; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
  <div id='child-2' style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: dimgray; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
</div>



By the example code it's like this,

what I expected should be like only 1 200*200 square with the mixed color of yellow green and both orange and dimgray in 0.5 opacity.

To put two divs on top of each other you need position:absolute on the child divs. If the parent div has position:relative you can still maintain the original position.

You've set the height and width to 300px, so why would you expect a "200*200 square"? Also, adding the colours on top of each other won't produce quite what you want (it's not like looking at a light source through coloured glass).

I found that 300px was a bit large when I was doing screenshot and then changed it to 200 but forgot edit it here ... but whatever. @David Thomas

The display: grid; on the parent div creates a grid layout.
The grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; on each child div places both elements in the same grid cell, causing them to overlap.


<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: yellowgreen; display: grid;">
  <div id="child-1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: orange; opacity: 0.5; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;"></div>
  <div id="child-2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: dimgray; opacity: 0.5; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;"></div>
</div>



